# Include_blank : wrong value in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a select field in my form which is not mandatory.
So I wrote this :

```
<% = f.select :company_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name"), :include_blank => true %>
```

When it is the "new" view, it works. But when I want to modify an existing object, the field is blank even if there is a company_id value.

Is it normal ?

Comment: Can you post what your edit and new methods on your controller look like?

Comment: `@product = Product.new` for new method, `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` for edit method and `@companies = Company.order('name ASC').all` for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `product_from_collection_for_select` needs a selected element.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

You can write this :

```
<% = f.select :company_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name", f.object.company_id), :include_blank => true %>
```